# Python path - handling home AND relative directory

Tags: python, path, filepath, pathlib

I'm trying to get the absolute path from a user input so there's no ambiguity within my script. I need to be able to handle both paths `~/Documents/repos/project` and `./project`.

Libraries like `os.path` and `pathlib` are able to resolve both cases - for example, in `pathlib`, `expanduser` resolves `~` and `resolve()` figures out relative paths, but neither can do both at the same time.

To elaborate, `expanduser` will strip relative paths of any periods, and `resolve()` will incorrectly resolve paths containing `~`. This means that combining the two will leave me with an incorrect path.

I could simply replace `~` with `Path.home()`, and then resolve the path, but I'm wondering if there's a "more correct", or simpler way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) and [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) together:

```
/var/tmp $ python
>>> from os.path import abspath, expanduser
>>> abspath(expanduser("./bar"))
'/var/tmp/bar'
>>> abspath(expanduser("~/foo"))
'/home/my.username/foo'
```

The `pathlib` method:

```
>>> PosixPath('./bar').expanduser().resolve()
PosixPath('/var/tmp/bar')
>>> PosixPath('~/foo').expanduser().resolve()
PosixPath('/home/my.username/foo')
```

Comment: The problem is when I have a path like `./foo` `abspath(expanduser("./foo")` gives me `/foo`, which is not correct.

Comment: See my updated answer. It will only give you `/foo` if your current directory is `/`, which is the correct absolute path.

Comment: Did some testing, and this is indeed correct - somehow my directory is changed to "/" when I specify the path using my default values (which includes a relative path). Thanks.